# Edit + Два Memo

Tags: delphi

Как решить такую задачу в Delphi XE4:

- На форме **Edit1 + memo1 + memo2 и кнопка**.

  1. Ввожу слово в **Edit1 - Игра**
  2. Ввожу **в memo1 в столбик** слова к примеру: хорошая игра отличная игра замечательная игра
  3. Нажимаю **кнопку и в memo2** выводиться результат такого вида:  **Игра|хорошая игра|отличная игра|замечательная игра**.
     И так при добавлении следующих слов. То есть что бы была возможность добавить много вариантов из Edit1 в memo2.

Comment: Совершенно непонятно, что вы хотите получить. Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример, наглядно демонстрирующий проблему.

Comment: Если выразиться проще то я хочу текст с edit соединить, через разделитель(:), с текстом в memo и записать в memo2. И так много слов.

Comment: Если ответ помог вам, отметьте его как принятый. Галочка слева от ответа)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Очищаем
Memo2.Clear;

// Для каждой строки в Memo1
for I := 0 to Memo1.Lines.Count - 1 do
  // Добавляем строку состоящую из Edit1, двоеточия и строки Memo1
  Memo2.Lines.Append(Edit1.Text + ': ' + Memo1.Lines[I]);
```